# Change default font size of VBE of Excel for Mac

Tags: excel, vba, macos

The default font size of VBE (Visual Basic Editor) of Excel for Mac is too small. There is a control in `Excel -> Preferences -> General -> Font size`, but it does not seem related to VBE.

Does anyone know how to change it?

PS:

Menu of Excel for Mac 15.15:

[image]

Menu of VBE:

[image]

Comment: Not got my mac to hand at the moment, but isn't there the same menu in the VBE? `Tools -> Options -> Editor Format` or use the help search tool to find the setting?

Comment: My version is `15.15`. There is no `Tools -> Options`.

Comment: Please see the update of my OP...

Comment: If you've not already had an answer, I'll look on my mac shortly when I've got it and see what options there are

Comment: So far, I have not got an answer yet...

Comment: Not forgotten, just still haven't got to my Mac yet. Will update as soon as I have it

Answer (score 1):

You just need to make sure that the VBE is the active window at the time, and then go to **Excel** > **Preferences** ( or press <kbd>⌘</kbd> + <kbd>,</kbd>)

From there you will presented with the Preferences window for the VBE, just select the **Editor Format** tab and you're good to go:

[image: Sreenshot of VBE preferences]

<sub>*(I'm using OS X El Capitan and Excel v14.5.7)*</sub>

Answer (score -1):

Don't know if this works differently on a Mac, but can you go to `Customize>Toolbars>Menu Bar>Reset` while on the VBA screen? (on Windows is accessed by right-clicking on the toolbar) If that brings the Tool menu back, then you can apply Macro Man's answer to modify the font size.